# No response from gunicorn master within 120 seconds

Tags: ubuntu, airflow, virtualenv, windows-subsystem-for-linux, airflow-webserver

Need assistance with launching my airflow webserver, the process takes longer than usual and I keep getting the same error.

```
[2023-11-02T01:46:30.297+0100] {webserver_command.py:225} ERROR - No response from gunicorn master within 120 seconds 
[2023-11-02T01:46:30.298+0100] {webserver_command.py:226} ERROR - Shutting down webserver
```

What I've done:
Reinstalled Ubuntu
cd project directory
created a virtual environment.
Set *export AIRFLOW_HOME=`pwd`* to my current directory
Uninstalled and re-installed apache-airflow in the environment, migrate db and created admin-user
changed both to 0

- worker_refresh_batch_size = 0
- worker_refresh_interval = 0
  changed port (e.g to 8081)

Here is what my current directory looks like:
[image: current directory]

I suspect the issues might be in the configured `$AIRFLOW_HOME` as it impacts the .cfg file, but i'm really not familiar with the installation process. and would appreciate your assistance.

```
dags_folder = /mnt/c/Users/buasc/PycharmProjects/airflow/dags
sql_alchemy_conn = sqlite:////mnt/c/Users/buasc/PycharmProjects/airflow/airflow.db
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this issue was from the set-up to installing airflow, solving the problem meant uninstalling and restarting the process from scratch.

Step 1: [Enable linux properties on windows](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-install-wsl2-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2-on-windows-10/) (windows 11)

- Go to Start. Search for "Turn Windows features on or off."
- Check the option
- - Windows Subsystem for Linux
- - Virtual Machine Platform

Step2: Visit Microsoft Store and download Ubuntu

- Install Ubuntu
- Launch *cmd* as adminstrator and run `wsl --install` to enable the windows subsytem
- - If the returns an error run the following:
- - `wsl --shutdown`
- - `wsl --list` this returns the installed linux distro
- - `wslconfig /unregister <distro>`
- - `wsl --install`
- A prompt returns to set a username and password, don't forget your credentials

Step 3: Set up *c* directory.

- Update everything: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
- On the (Ubuntu) terminal `cd ~` to your root directory
  Now we will configure the file system to direct to the *c* without mounting it (without using `/mnt/` prefix):
- `sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf` to modify it by pasting the following, save and exit with ctrl+s ctrl+x:

```
[automount]

root = /
options = "metadata"
```

- Run `nano ~/.bashrc`, insert the line below, save and exit with ctrl+s ctrl+x

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=/c/Users/<PARENT_DIR>/<PROJECT_DIR>
```

- close your terminal and restart
- Test that everything works:
- - `cd ~`
- - `cd \`
- - `ls`: Now you should see the *c* directory
- - `echo $AIRFLOW_HOME`: you should see the directory you set

Step 4: Install Packages.

- `sudo apt get virtualenv`
- `cd $AIRFLOW_HOME`
- `virtualenv <env-name>`: creates a virtual environment with the env-name
- `source <env-name>/bin/activate`: to activate the environment.

[Install airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start.html):

- `pip install apache-airflow`
- `airflow db migrate`

```
airflow users create \
   --username admin \
   --firstname Peter \
   --lastname Parker \
   --role Admin \
   --email spiderman@superhero.org
```

then a prompt asks for you to set a login password

- now, run `airflow webserver --port 8080` to launch the webserver

The issue from the original attempt was having to mount with the `/mnt/` prefix and not wanting to use docker. Very thankful for the following tutorials:

https://towardsdatascience.com/run-apache-airflow-on-windows-10-without-docker-3c5754bb98b4

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/install-apache-airflow-on-windows-without-docker/